# GWT adding a ClickHandler to a DOM element

Tags: gwt

lets say i have a custom widget which has a ClickHandler. Here's the example:

```
public class TestWidget extends Composite {

private static TestWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(TestWidgetUiBinder.class);

interface TestWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, TestWidget> {
}

@UiField
Button button;

public TestWidget(String firstName) {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    button.setText(firstName);
}

@UiHandler("button")
void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
    Window.alert("Hello!");
}
```

}

When i try to add this Widget like this:

```
    TestWidget testWidget = new TestWidget("myTestWidget");
    RootPanel.get().add(testWidget);
```

everything is fine. If i click on my button i get the message i expect.
However if i add it like this:

```
TestWidget testWidget = new TestWidget("myTestWidget");
    RootPanel.getBodyElement().appendChild(testWidget.getElement());
```

my click event is not being fired. I'm struggeling to understand why.
It would be nice if someone could explain this to me or link me to an resource where i can read this up. Finally i would like to know if it is possible to add the clickhandler afterwards i appended the child event and if that way is recommended. Thanks it advance for help.

kuku

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `add()`, `Widget.onAttach()` is called on the widget that is being added to the panel. onAttach does some work to register the widget to receive events. `appendChild()` simply attaches one DOM element to another and does nothing else. You should be able to get events working in the second case by doing this:

```
Element element = testWidget.getElement();
RootPanel.getBodyElement().appendChild(element);
DOM.sinkEvents(element,
    Event.getTypeInt(ClickEvent.getType().getName())
    | DOM.getEventsSunk(element);
```

However, I haven't tested this and I wouldn't recommend that you use it in a real application. Using `add()` is definitely preferred, using `appendChild()` in this way has no advantages and may lead to unexpected behaviour.