# Click Handler working on widget but NOT on Element

Tags: gwt

I am creating an Anchor as follows:

```java
Anchor a = new Anchor( "Click Me" );
```

Then I add a click handler:

```java
a.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        GWT.log("Anchor Clicked");
    }
} );
```

I want to add the Anchor to a LI element. Since I don't have any Widgets for UL and LI, I use the following construct:

```java
public class ElementPanel extends ComplexPanel {

    public ElementPanel(String tagName) {
        setElement(DOM.createElement(tagName));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w) {
        add(w, getElement());
    }
}
```

I create my UL element:

```java
ElementPanel ul = new ElementPanel(UListElement.TAG);
```

I create a LI element:

```java
ElementPanel li = new ElementPanel(LIElement.TAG);
```

I add my Anchor to LI, then I add LI to UL (after which I add to the document):

```java
li.add(a);
ul.add(li);
```

This works fine. If instead I change the previous lines as follows, I don't see a log message:

```java
li.getElement().appendChild(a.getElement());
ul.add(li);
```

Similarly, if instead I try this, I also do not see a message:

```java
li.add(a);
ul.getElement().appendChild(li.getElement());
```

Previously, I had the UL element in the UIBinder. But since I was not successful in adding a click handler to an Element, I have to resort to the above approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how events are handled in GWT: the widget needs to be *attached*, and that generally means adding it to a container chain up to a `RootPanel`. See [https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks#GWT's_Solution](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks#GWT%27s_Solution) for the details.

The easiest way to have `<ul><li>` if your structure doesn't change dynamically is to use an `HTMLPanel` (and it's even easier with UiBinder).

If the structure is dynamic, then possibly make a `ComplexPanel` whose root element is a `UListElement` and which wraps all child widgets into a `LIElement`. Have a look at the internals of `ComplexPanel`, you'll see that it *attaches* and *detaches* the child widgets whenever they are added/removed while the panel itself is *attached*, or whenever the panel is *attached* / *detached*.

Comment: Which is what I did with my ElementPanel class which extends ComplexPanel. All the code above is in a Composite type class which uses a UI binder who's root element is HTMLPanel. The whole thing is added into a DIV element from the onModuleLoad method (via RootPanel). I'm trying to understand why the change I noted at the end of my post broke the click Handler. Why does is seem to make a difference whether you add a Widget vs an Element.

Comment: When you add the widget's element, the widget is not _attached_ and thus it doesn't listen to the events. BTW I was suggesting making one panel that uses both `<ul>` and `<li>`, not one for each (just like `HorizontalPanel` uses `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` for instance)

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I did find the following post which further explains about element attaching and events in GWT: [gwt-adding-a-clickhandler-to-a-dom-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081158/gwt-adding-a-clickhandler-to-a-dom-element)