# GWT adding dynamic menu item to a custom built menu

Tags: dom, gwt

I have built a menu using the regular html in GWT as show below.

```html
 <g:HTMLPanel>
  <div id="navigation">
      <div id="menuLeft" class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <g:Anchor ui:field="homeLink" styleName="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;Home</g:Anchor>
     </li>
     
     <li class="active">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>&nbsp;Businesses</a>
      <ul ui:field="businessesMenu">
       <li>
        <g:Anchor ui:field="enrollBusiness">Enroll Business </g:Anchor>
       </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              .....
```

as it is rendering the very nicely using css provided. All is well till this point, now comes the requirement; to this I have to add dynamic menu item based on some business logic, which means I have to add more  s to the existing menu .

I'm able to build/add dynamic item but not able to add an event handler.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Dom to add the dynamic menu, you can refer this for adding click handlers.
[you can refer this to add handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081158/gwt-adding-a-clickhandler-to-a-dom-element).

Comment: Hi I implemented the proposed the fix but it didn't work for me I did that exact same that its presented in the solution. 
LIElement menuItem = Document.get().createLIElement();
Anchor itemLink = new Anchor();
itemLink.setText("Business 1");
itemLink.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
   }
 });
  
Element linkElement = itemLink.getElement();
menuItem.appendChild(linkElement);
businessesMenu.appendChild(menuItem);
DOM.sinkEvents(linkElement,Event.getTypeInt(ClickEvent.getType().getName())| DOM.getEventsSunk(linkElement));